# Массовое сравнение таблиц MySql и удаление строк

Tags: mysql

В базе есть таблица "Users", в ней есть колонка user_id (числовое значение)
Любой юзер может создать объявление(строку) в таблице "obj", которому будет присвоен obj_id (числовое значение), а также в таблице obj есть колонка obj_author, значение которой равно user_id.

```
То есть, я создаю юзера, получаю user_id = 16001
Создаю объявление c obj_id = 3200, и obj_author = 16001
Создаю еще одно объявление c obj_id = 3201, и obj_author = 16001
```

99% спамеров создают только профили, соответственно, если у профиля нет объявлений, его можно удалять.
Нужно для каждой строки таблицы obj сделать сравнение
Если user_id = author, то оставляем, если нет,то строку с данным user_id удаляем.

Это можно как то сделать?

Comment: Да. Почитайте про `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
delete from users ud where ud.user_id in (Select 
  user_id 
from 
  users u
  left join objects o on o.user_id=u.user_id
where 
  IS_NULL(o.user_id))
```

Comment: Подскажите что такое в коде: ud, u, o?

Comment: Если так писать:
https://ibb.co/19VgBBY
То выдает ошибку " #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'ud.id' в 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"
А если так: 
https://ibb.co/x6bLPTM
То имитацию проходит, и вроде как должно работать (затрагивает 15000 строк)
Но когда пытаюсь реально выполнить, то тоже выдает ошибку
"#1093 - Не допускается указание таблицы 'e1xc7_users' в списке таблиц FROM для внесения в нее изменений"

Comment: @Amigo9876 Зависит от настроек оптимизации MySQL и от версии, если подзапрос пойдет через временную таблицу( настройки по умолчанию для версий 5.х) - никакой ошибки не будет, т.к. сначало будет выполнен подзапрос, сформирована временная таблица, и только после по выборке из временной таблицы пойдет удаление, возможно в вашем случае иная версия MySQL либо изменены настройки оптимизации запросов. П.с. для версии MySQL 8+, совет был бы иным - использовать WITH.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Владимиру Клыкову, он дал нужное направление, но его код написан на скорую руку, и выдает ошибку. 
Мне нужно удалить строки из таблицы e1xc7_users, если значение столбца id не существует в столбце obj_author любой строки в таблице e1xc7_obj
Вот работающее решение.

```
DELETE u 
FROM e1xc7_users u  INNER JOIN 
(SELECT us.id FROM e1xc7_users us
LEFT JOIN
    e1xc7_obj o ON us.id = o.obj_author
WHERE
    o.obj_author IS NULL) u2
ON u.id = u2.id
```